# Convertir caracteres especiales de Javascript con Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, unicode

Tengo que convertir strings que vienen en un json como este por ejemplo:

> {"detalle":"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}

en:

> {"detalle":"el Expediente N° 30 de la Resolución 11..."}

para almacenarlo luego en una base de datos MySQL.

probé:

`json.dumps({"detalle":"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
'{"detalle": "el Expediente N\\\\u00b0\\\\u00a030 de la Resoluci\\\\u00f3n 11..."}'`

pero no funciona.

¿Como lo podría convertir usando Python?

**SOLUCIÓN**

Abrir el json como texto plano y decodificar los caracteres escapados:

```
with open('nombre_del_fichero.json', 'r') as fichero:
    # decodifica los caracteres escapados
    data = unicode(fichero.read()).decode('unicode-escape')
    fichero.close()
```

Luego:

```
data.encode('utf8')
```

Espero que a alguien más le sea útil.

Comment: La cadena supongo que vendrá en un campo del JSON. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo del JSON mínimo que contiene esa cadena, pero que sea JSON válido? (porque una cadena sin más no lo es, ha de venir dentro de un objeto o lista json). Por otro lado, a la hora de enviarlo a la base de datos ¿puedes enviarle directamente Unicode y la base de datos lo convierte? ¿O tienes que enviarle directamente los bytes ya codificados? En el segundo caso, ¿en utf8 o en qué encoding?

Comment: La codificación en la base es "utf8" ya modifiqué el ejemplo como un json válido.

Comment: Es lícito que te respondas a tí mismo. Es decir, puedes crear una respuesta en lugar de editar la pregunta. Es lícito también que marques como aceptada tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR (o respuesta hiper-breve)

```
recibido = funcion_que_recibe_el_json()
bytes_para_sql = json.dumps(json.loads(recibido), ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
```

## Larguísima explicación para quien quiera saber más.

Es complicado responder sin tener todos los detalles de cómo obtienes esa cadena, en qué formato viene, etc. pues el tema de Unicode y sus encodings no es sencillo, y se complica además con la forma en que Python muestra un resultado cuando lo vuelcas en el intérprete interactivo.

Así que he preferido hacer una respuesta larga que explique bien toda la "teoría" para que tú mismo puedas hallar la solución más adecuada a tu caso. ¡Perdón por el rollazo!

Empecemos por algún sitio.

### 1. Entrada de caracteres Unicode en un listado Python

En python3 no es necesario declarar estas cadenas de ninguna forma especial, en concreto no hay por qué ponerles delante una `u` para indicar que son Unicode. Esto era en Python2

En Python3 una cadena estándar (`str`) puede contener caracteres Unicode, que puedes introducir de dos formas diferentes:

- Si tu teclado tiene la letra en cuestión, por ejemplo la eñe, puedes teclearla sin más como parte de la cadena así:

  ```
  ejemplo1 = "Hay una eñe en esta frase"
  ```
- Si no tienes acceso a esa letra en el teclado ni ninguna otra forma de introducirla en tu editor, o bien prefieres no hacerlo así, también puedes usar la forma `\uXXXX` siendo XXXX el código Unicode de la letra en cuestión, en hexadecimal. Esta forma vale para códigos Unicode que quepan en 16 bits. Si necesitas más bits, puedes usar la forma `\UXXXXXXXX` (la `U` es mayúscula aquí), en cuyo caso escribirás 8 cifras hexadecimales detrás.

  Así, la misma cadena de antes podemos introducirla también así (la eñe tiene código unicode `f1`, o bien `00f1` que es lo mismo pero con 16 bits):

  ```
  ejemplo2 = "Hay una e\u00f1e en esta frase"
  ejemplo3 = "Hay una e\U000000f1e en esta frase"
  ```

Las tres cadenas son iguales en realidad:

```
>>> ejemplo1 == ejemplo2 == ejemplo3
True
```

Son solo diferentes formas de introducir la misma información.

## 2. Cómo Python vuelca las cadenas en el intérprete interactivo

Cuando vuelcas una cadena en un intérprete interactivo, Python te muestra una forma "representable" de la cadena, que es una posible forma en la que podrías teclearla como parte de un programa. Es decir, la mostrará entre comillas, y todos sus caracteres imprimibles los mostrará "tal cual" y los no imprimibles los mostrará como "secuencias de escape".

En el caso anterior, las tres cadenas contienen la misma información como hemos visto, por lo que mostrará las tres de la misma forma. Todos los caracteres que forman esa cadena son imprimibles (incluyendo la eñe) y mostraría lo siguiente:

```
>>> ejemplo1
'Hay una eñe en esta frase'
```

Salvo por las comillas, que ha elegido usar simples en lugar de dobles, se ve igual que cuando lo introdujimos. Pero cualquiera de los otros dos ejemplos los mostrará igual que el ejemplo 1, y no como fueron introducidos en el programa, porque en realidad lo que está guardado en memoria es lo mismo en los tres casos porque en los tres casos la `ñ` dio lugar al mismo carácter Unicode:

```
>>> ejemplo2
'Hay una eñe en esta frase'

>>> ejemplo3
'Hay una eñe en esta frase'
```

Ahora bien, si en la cadena apareciera algún carácter no visible (un tabulador, un retorno de carro, etc), esos los mostraría como códigos de control. Por ejemplo, un código de control Unicode es el que tiene por código `00a0` que es un *UNBREAKABLE SPACE*, o espacio de no-separación. Ese carácter no podemos introducirlo por el teclado, pero sí en su forma `\u00a0`. Otro ejemplo:

```
ejemplo4 = "Hay una e\u00f1e\u00a0en\u00a0esta\nfrase"
```

Aquí he elegido meter la `ñ` en su forma `\uXXXX`, y también he cambiado un par de espacios de los que contenía la frase por espacios "irrompibles", que he introducido también en su forma `\u00a0`. También he elegido meter un retorno de carro antes de la última palabra (`\n`).

Si vuelco en el intérprete esa cadena, me mostrará:

```
>>> ejemplo4
'Hay una eñe\xa0en\xa0esta\nfrase'
```

Python ha elegido mostrar la `ñ` "normal" (por ser un carácter visible), pero el espacio irrompible lo muestra como `\xa0`, por ser un carácter de control invisible. La forma `\xa0` es otra posible forma en la que podríamos haber introducido el código Unicode, en lugar de `\u00a0` (válida sólo para códigos Unicode que quepan en 8 bits). El retorno de carro ha elegido mostrarlo como `\n`, pero otras representaciones válidas podrían ser `\x0a`, `\u000a`, o `\U0000000a`, pues el código Unicode del carácter "nueva línea" es 10 (`a` en hexadecimal)

**Sin embargo**, si imprimo la cadena con `print()`, los caracteres de control serán "ejecutados" por la terminal. Así, los espacios irrompibles se mostrarán como espacios (a simple vista indistinguibles de los normales) y el "nueva línea" dará lugar a una nueva línea:

```
>>> print(ejemplo4)
Hay una eñe en esta
frase
```

Por tanto no debe confundirte lo que ves en el intérprete al volcar una variable. Aunque veas "códigos raros" dentro, como `\xa0` o incluso `\xf1` (Python podría haber elegido mostrar así la `ñ`), eso no significa que la cadena contenga esas secuencias de caracteres, sino que sólo es la forma en que Python elige representarlo en el volcado.

## 3. Unicode en JSON

Resulta que JSON también usa el convenio `\uXXXX` como python para representar caracteres dentro de una cadena.

Por tanto podríamos recibir una cadena JSON que contenga una eñe así: `\u00f1`, pero "literalmente", es decir, esa eñe estaría representada como una secuencia de seis caracteres ASCII, el primero sería `\`, el segundo sería `u`, etc. Pero para JSON esa secuencia de 6 caracteres significa uno solo. Cuando JavaScript procesara esa cadena, convertiría esa secuencia de 5 caracteres en una `ñ` que sería lo que guardaría en una hipotética variable. Y al serializar esa variable como JSON de nuevo podría convertirla en los seis caracteres `\u00f1`. Esta forma de representarlo tiene la ventaja de que sólo está usando caracteres ASCII, y no depende por tanto de *encodings* como UTF-8

Podemos simular una cadena así en Python introduciendo "literalmente" esa secuencia. Para que Python no interprete de forma especial la secuencia `\u`, hay que "escapar" la barra, lo cual se logra duplicándola:

```
ejemplo5 = "Hay una e\\u00f1e en esta frase"
```

Aunque hemos duplicado la barra, es sólo para indicar a Python que no le dé significado especial. Quedará almacenada una sola vez. Queda claro si la imprimimos:

```
>>> print(ejemplo5)
Hay una e\u00f1e en esta frase
```

Y si la volcamos, la veremos duplicada pues así es como se representa un carácter `\` literal dentro de una cadena:

```
>>> ejemplo5
'Hay una e\\u00f1e en esta frase'
```

Así pues, podemos entender que esta variable `ejemplo5` podría ser algo que hayas recibido vía red desde un servidor que te responda en JSON.

## 4. Des-serializando el JSON

El módulo `json` te permite convertir una cadena JSON que hayas recibido de la red en una variable Python. Como parte de esa conversión "decodificará" los `\u` que aparezcan en las cadenas, para generar cadenas Unicode Python como las de los primeros ejemplos que vimos.

Lo más difícil de esta respuesta es poder ponerte un ejemplo Python sin conexión de red.

Supongamos que la variable `respuesta` es la que tiene una cadena recibida de la red, y esa cadena contiene JSON. Supongamos que la cadena es Unicode (pues todas las cadenas Python lo son, y se supone que la biblioteca que ha recibido la respuesta de la red ya te la ha convertido a Unicode), pero supongamos que pese a ser una cadena unicode, todos los caracteres que contiene son ASCII, porque el servidor los ha representado como `\u...`,  siendo la `\` literal.

Es decir, podemos simular con el código siguiente la cadena recibida:

```
respuesta = '{"datos": "Hay una e\\u00f1e en esta frase"}'
```

Para que quede más claro, imprimo esa cadena:

```
>>> type(respuesta)
str

>>> print(respuesta)
{"datos": "Hay una e\u00f1e en esta frase"}
```

De momento es una cadena, aunque tiene la misma sintaxis que tendría un diccionario python. Para convertirla en tal diccionario (y de paso traducir los `\u`), podemos hacer uso de `json.loads()`:

```
>>> datos = json.loads(respuesta)
>>> type(datos)
dict

>>> datos
{"datos": "Hay una eñe en esta frase"}
```

¡Ya estamos cerca!

## 5. Conversión a UTF-8 del resultado

Cómo seguir a partir de ahora depende de lo que quieras enviarle a MySQL ¿Se trata de enviarle sólo la cadena contenida en el campo `"dato"`? ¿O el diccionario completo en JSON?

### Sólo la cadena

Entonces extraes esa cadena con `datos["datos"]` y la codificas en UTF-8:

```
>>> bytes_a_enviar = datos["datos"].encode("utf-8")
>>> bytes_a_enviar
b'Hay una e\xc3\xb1e en esta frase'
```

Fíjate que la representación que muestra Python comienza por `b` (para indicar que es una secuencia de bytes), y ha cambiado la `ñ` por dos bytes de valor `c3` y `1e`, que es su representación UTF-8.

### El diccionario completo en JSON

Entonces tienes volver a serializar la variable `datos`, usando `json.dumps()`. A esta función le puedes pasar un `ensure_ascii=True` para que la secuencia de letras resultantes sean solo ASCII (y cambiará lo que no sea ASCII por su representación `\uXXXX`), o puedes pasarle `ensure_ascii=False`, con lo que no hará eso, sino que incluirá los caracteres no ASCII tal cual en la cadena resultante.

En cualquiera de los dos casos podemos recodificar el resultado como UTF-8, si bien en el primer caso esa recodificación no hará nada, ya que todos los caracteres eran ASCII de todas formas.

```
caso1 = json.dumps(datos, ensure_ascii=True).encode("utf-8")
caso2 = json.dumps(dato, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
```

Si volcamos ambos casos por la consola del intérprete:

```
>>> caso1
b'{"datos": "Hay una e\\u00f1e en esta frase"}'

>>> caso2
b'{"datos": "Hay una e\xc3\xb1e en esta frase"}'
```

Observa que en ambos casos tengo cadenas de bytes (la `b` inicial), pero en el primer caso todos los bytes del resultado son ASCII. El `\\` se muestra duplicado, pero sólo hay realmente uno. En el segundo caso en cambio aparecen bytes no ascii (`c3`, `1e`) que son la `ñ` en UTF-8.

Es importante remarcar que **ambos son JSON válido**, por lo que en principio cualquiera de los dos te serviría para ser almacenado en la base de datos. Todo depende de cuál prefieras tú, según cómo se vayan a procesar luego.

**Claro que** para quedarse con el `caso1` no hacían falta tantas vueltas, pues al final ¡resulta que es igual a la cadena recibida de la red en `respuesta`!

Comment: Mucho trabajo y tiempo pero no responde la pregunta.  Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Perdona, creo que sí la he respondido. Como me faltaba información, he cubierto muchas posibilidades para que elijas la que encaja en tu caso. Si lo prefieres, dame más detalles (código que recibe el JSON, y si a SQL quieres enviarle la cadena o el JSON entero) y te puedo dar el código concreto. Pero en cualquier caso, la solución aparece al final

Comment: @jmd He añadido la sección TL:DR por si solo quieres la receta, para que no tengas que leerte el resto del rollo, que quedará ahi para referencia por si a alguien más le interesa

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar codificar la linea, en python3 seria:

```
import codecs
a = codecs.encode("el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11...",'utf-8')
a = a.decode().replace("\xa0"," ")
print(a)
```

Te dará como resultado:

```
'el Expediente N° 30 de la Resolución 11...'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero encontré otra variante.